# Все платежи в приложении play market возвращаются покупателям по непонятной причине

Tags: android, playmarket

Проблема в следующем есть приложение в play market, в нем через библиотеку inappbilling я продаю ограниченный контент. Но все платежи которые оплачивались до данного времени через 3 дня возвращались покупателям. Я тоже купил на свои платежные данные товар и деньги опять таки вернулись, хотя я возврат не запрашивал.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Это что-то совсем необычное. Пишите в тех.поддержку Google Play

Comment: Написал я в саппорт вот что ответили: They've replied that purchases made on Play must be acknowledged within 3 days, or they will be automatically refunded. Что значит покупки должны быть подтверждены?

Comment: Тех. поддержка гугла очень плохая. Попробуйте им ещё раз написать. Может быть они точнее ответят что-то.

Comment: Понял попробую. Спасибо, отпишусь по результату.